# hive sql - data issue - case statement - add_month

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

i have to sum col_n for every last day of month for 1yr from load_date.

query 1:

```
  select 
     id1,id2,date_col,
    sum(
    CASE
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-11)) then     col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-10)) then     col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-9)) then     col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-8)) then     col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-7)) then col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-6)) then col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-5)) then     col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-4)) then     col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-3)) then col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-2)) then col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-1)) then col_n
    WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date('2016-03-31') then col_n
END  
    ) as col_n_sum  
    from table_1 table_1 
    where id2=7 and id1 = 2
    group by  id1,id2 ,date_col
```

[output of query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqe6n.png)

query 2 : just select from table -without case statement : [output of select query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpXO6.png)

Problem : why it is giving null for April,june .... though there is data In table for all months.

if I hardcode april then I m getting data - Query -

```
CASE WHEN to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date('2015-04-30') then col_n .
```

even -Query -

```
select * from table_1 where (to_date(table_1.date_col) = to_date(add_months('2016-03-31',-11)) ) and  id1 = 2 and id2 = 7 giving data .
```

Add_month is not working with case or something I m missing.

I m using Clouder HUE -Hive.

Comment: The query makes no sense. `date_col` should probably be removed from the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses

Comment: yes ...its just for debugging what all date are coming

Comment: If you think that `add_months` does not work then try to simplify your query to show only exactly what is not working, and provide data example please to reproduce.